# Material Design Lite with ReactJS (import/require Issue)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, material-design-lite

I am trying to use [Google's Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io) with ReactJS. I am using [Spinner Loading](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#loading-section/spinner) & [Text Field](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section) Component of MDL library.

But, when I switch routes with React Router, the animation does not take place & when I refresh the page, it works fine. I think, this is probably because MDL components are not getting upgraded. Then, I am trying to use `componentHandler.upgradeDom()`, but Console throws an error, `app.js:27160 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgradeDom' of undefined`.

Here is the code,

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var PropTypes = React.PropTypes;
var MDLite = require('material-design-lite');
var componentHandler = MDLite.componentHandler;

var styles = {
  loader: {
    marginTop: '70px',
  }
}

var Loading = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active" style={styles.loader}></div>
    );
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  },
});

module.exports = Loading;
```

I also tried to log **MDLite** variable in Console with `console.log(MDLite)`. But, it is showing me an **empty Object {}**. I am using **webpack** & have installed Material Design Lite with **NPM**, `npm install material-design-lite --save`.

My question is how can I import/require MDL properly & use `componentHandler.upgradeDom()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself. There are two ways through which you can achieve this.

> **The Lazy Way**

In `node_modules/material-design-lite/material.js`, edit & add the following code in the end as mentioned below.

> ```
> // You can also export just componentHandler
> if (typeof module === 'object') {
>   module.exports = window;
> }
> ```

Your **material.js** file will look like this.

```
;(function() {
  .
  .
  .
  componentHandler.register({
    constructor: MaterialRipple,
    classAsString: 'MaterialRipple',
    cssClass: 'mdl-js-ripple-effect',
    widget: false
  });

  // You can also export just componentHandler
  if (typeof module === 'object') {
    module.exports = window;
  }

}());
```

In your React Component file, `require` like this,

```
var MDLite = require('material-design-lite/material');
var componentHandler = MDLite.componentHandler;
```

Then, you can call `componentHandler.upgradeDom()` to upgrade MDL elements.

Note that you can also write `module.exports = componentHandler;` if you only want to import `componentHandler`.

> **The Webpack Way**

Personally, I would prefer the webpack way as it is much cleaner & you need not to edit the module files yourself.

Install **exports-loader**, `npm install exports-loader --save-dev`. Then, in your **webpack.config.js**, specify loaders as

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'exports-loader!babel-loader'
  }
]
```

In your React Component file, you can `require` componentHandler as

```
var componentHandler = require('exports?componentHandler!material-design-lite/material');
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Your solution works fine, but we need to upgrade the DOM, do you think it will effect the performance?