# "has no exported member" Error in my MTL module

Tags: angular, material-design-lite

:grinning: Anyone to help me with that ?
I have a class MDL :
MaterialDesignLiteUpgradeElements.ts

```
import {Directive, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
declare var componentHandler;
@Directive({
    selector: '[mdl]'
})
export class MDL implements AfterViewInit {
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    }
}
```

And Following this stack post : [Material Design Lite tooltips not working with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878521/material-design-lite-tooltips-not-working-with-angular-2)
I Added this :

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
  }
```

In the class managing the view using MTL
But it say :

```
MaterialDesignLiteUpgradeElements has no exported member "componentHandler"
```

The console error :

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgradeDom' of undefined
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not into Angular2 but, I faced the same issue in ReactJS with Material Design Lite (MDL).

The reason why you are getting `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgradeDom' of undefined` error is MDL does not export any module by default. You can follow the below suggestions to export the module.

1. Either you have to export `componentHandler` manually from `material.js` file & `import/require` in your Component file
2. Or, if you are using any bundler like Webpack, you can make use of exports-loader & then use `import/require` to export `componentHandler`

I have given a detailed description here [SO/Material Design Lite with ReactJS (import/require Issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809425/material-design-lite-with-reactjs-import-require-issue/36812136#36812136)

Hope it helps!